# Tengo problemas con Grid Layout Java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema en el cual tengo que crear 3 cuadrados de color gris juntos en la fila 2 empezando por la izquierda y siempre que lo pongo se me pone en el medio , y no tengo manera de como solucionarlo . Me podriais ayudar porfa . Os lo agradezco

Os paso el codigo

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame ventana = new JFrame("AC5");
        PanelConFondo panelFondo = new PanelConFondo();
        panelFondo.setLayout(null);

        JLabel titulo = new JLabel("MONKEY WARS");
        titulo.setBounds(30, 30, 200, 30);
        titulo.setOpaque(false);
        titulo.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        titulo.setFont(titulo.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 25));
        panelFondo.add(titulo);

        JPanel panelCuadradoVerde = new JPanel();
        panelCuadradoVerde.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panelCuadradoVerde.setBounds(30, 70, 350, 350);
        panelFondo.add(panelCuadradoVerde);

        Border bordeCompuesto = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK), // borde negro en el exterior
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 5) // borde gris en el interior
        );

        // Ponemos el borde en el panel
        panelCuadradoVerde.setBorder(bordeCompuesto);

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.setBounds(580, 30, 100, 30); // ajustar coordenadas x e y según sea necesario
        panelFondo.add(startButton);

        JPanel panelCuadradoBrillante = new JPanel();
        panelCuadradoBrillante.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panelCuadradoBrillante.setBounds(panelCuadradoVerde.getX() + panelCuadradoVerde.getWidth() + 10, panelCuadradoVerde.getY(), panelCuadradoVerde.getWidth(), panelCuadradoVerde.getHeight());

        Border bordeCompuestoBrillante = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 3), // borde blanco en el exterior
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 5) // borde gris claro en el interior
        );

        panelCuadradoBrillante.setBorder(bordeCompuestoBrillante);

        // Agregar botones dentro del panelCuadradoBrillante
        JButton attackerButton = new JButton("Attacker");
        attackerButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        attackerButton.setBounds(10, panelCuadradoBrillante.getHeight() / 2 - 20, 100, 40);
        panelCuadradoBrillante.add(attackerButton);

        JButton defenderButton = new JButton("Defender");
        defenderButton.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        defenderButton.setBounds(panelCuadradoBrillante.getWidth() - 110, panelCuadradoBrillante.getHeight() / 2 - 20, 100, 40);
        panelCuadradoBrillante.add(defenderButton);
        panelFondo.add(panelCuadradoBrillante);

        JPanel panelCuadrados = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));

// Agregar 3 cuadrados al panelCuadrados
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            JPanel cuadrado = new JPanel();
            cuadrado.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            panelCuadrados.add(cuadrado);
        }

// Establecer la posición del panelCuadrados en el fondo de la ventana
        panelCuadrados.setBounds(5, 5, 100, 100);
        panelCuadradoVerde.add(panelCuadrados);




        panelFondo.setLayout(null);

        ventana.add(panelFondo);
        ventana.setSize(800, 600);


        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ventana.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Josep, podrías subir una imagen de como querés que queden?.

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr que los tres cuadrados grises aparezcan juntos en la fila 2 comenzando desde la izquierda, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Cambiar la disposición del panel que contiene los tres cuadrados de
  `GridLayout` a `FlowLayout`.
- Establecer la posición del panel de los tres cuadrados grises
  utilizando `setBounds()` para que comience desde la esquina superior
  izquierda de la fila 2.
- Establecer el tamaño del panel de los tres cuadrados grises para que
  se ajuste al tamaño de los cuadrados.

El siguiente código debería resolver el problema:

```
JPanel panelCuadrados = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
// Cambiar la disposición a FlowLayout y alinear a la izquierda

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    JPanel cuadrado = new JPanel();
    cuadrado.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    panelCuadrados.add(cuadrado);
}

// Establecer la posición y tamaño del panel de los tres cuadrados grises
panelCuadrados.setBounds(panelCuadradoVerde.getX() + 5, panelCuadradoVerde.getY() + 70, 90, 30);

panelCuadradoVerde.add(panelCuadrados);
```

Es importante tener en cuenta que la posición y el tamaño de los componentes en Swing están relacionados con el contenedor principal y los componentes que los contienen. Por lo tanto, es posible que deba ajustar las coordenadas y los tamaños de los componentes en función de la configuración de su interfaz de usuario.